# I have created a jquery carousel, and using if condition to run and stop the carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a jQuery carousel with if condition to run and stop it, if the checkBox is checked the carousel run towards left it is happening, else if the checkBox is UNchecked the carousel needs to stop, i don't know to do this, someone please help me to do this

```
$("#checkBox").click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        carouselRun();
    }
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        carouselStop();
    }
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var mslideWidth = 500, mslideHeight = 105, speed = 3000,
     slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length,
     slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width(),
     slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height(),
        sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
  
    function carouselRun(){
        setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
  }, speed);
 };
    function carouselStop(){
  setInterval(function () {
   moveLeft();
  }, speed).stop();
 };
  
    $('#checkBox').click(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
   carouselRun();
  }
        else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false){
   carouselStop();
  }
 });  
  
 if (mslideWidth != 0 || mslideHeight != 0){
  slideWidth = mslideWidth;
  slideHeight = mslideHeight;
  $('#slider ul li').css('width',mslideWidth);
  $('#slider ul li').css('height',mslideHeight);
 }
 $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
 $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
  $('#slider ul').animate({
   left: + slideWidth
  }, function () {
   $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
   $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
  });
 };

 function moveRight() {
  $('#slider ul').animate({
   left: - slideWidth
  },function () {
   $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
   $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
  });
 };

 $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
  moveLeft();
 });

 $('a.control_next').click(function () {
  moveRight();
 });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600); 

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div> 

<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use clearInterval function to stop the timer and the carousel. Change `carouselRun`and `carouselStop`functions with following and add `interval` variable to the place you defined your variables.

```
function carouselRun(){
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, speed);
};

function carouselStop(){
    clearInterval(interval);
};
```

Working example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var mslideWidth = 500, mslideHeight = 105, speed = 3000,
 slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length,
 slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width(),
 slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height(),
  sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth,
      interval;
  
 function carouselRun(){
  interval = setInterval(function () {
   moveRight();
  }, speed);
 };
  function carouselStop(){
  clearInterval(interval);
 };
  
  $('#checkBox').click(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
   carouselRun();
  }
    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
   carouselStop();
  }
 });  
  
 if(mslideWidth != 0 || mslideHeight != 0){
  slideWidth = mslideWidth;
  slideHeight = mslideHeight;
  $('#slider ul li').css('width',mslideWidth);
  $('#slider ul li').css('height',mslideHeight);
 }
 $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
 $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

  function moveLeft() {
  $('#slider ul').animate({
   left: + slideWidth
  }, function () {
   $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
   $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
  });
 };

 function moveRight() {
  $('#slider ul').animate({
   left: - slideWidth
  },function () {
   $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
   $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
  });
 };

 $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
  moveLeft();
 });

 $('a.control_next').click(function () {
  moveRight();
 });
 
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600); 

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div> 

<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```